# Android facebook sdk import error

Tags: android, android-facebook

i had download facebook skd import it in my eclipse add v4 jar file and change complier to 1.6 but yet it give me error in class FacebookAppLinkResolver

`import bolts.AppLink;
import bolts.AppLinkResolver;
import bolts.Continuation;
import bolts.Task;`

[image]
above are not import

Answer (score 9):

1.Open your project properties

2.Select "Java Build Path" from left side menu

3.Select "Libraries" tab

4.Press "Add External Jar"

5.MOST IMPORTANT STEPS :-
   Select "bolts" jar file of "libs" folder of YOUR CURRENT PROJECT LOCATION(Path Should be
   of your project only and not the android sdk).

6.Select "Order and Export" tab and "TICK" the checkbox of "android-support-v4.jar"

Answer (score 8):

Download sdk for Bolts library from 
 https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android
and add this project with facebook sdk project.

Answer (score 7):

Or if you're using Gradle you can add this to your Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.3'
}
```

Facebook is also available so you don't have to add that manually either. To include both use the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.3'
}
```

You can check for the latest version of Bolts [here](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1700048106).

Answer (score 0):

amalBit's answer works great for Eclipse. Here is the Android Studio equivalent.
I encountered this error after updating to the latest Facebook SDK for Android.

1. File ->
2. Project Structure ->
3. Select the Facebook module on the left
4. Select the Dependencies tab
5. Press the + button at the bottom of the
   window
6. Select File Dependency
7. In the libs folder, you should see the
   bolts.jar file you copied over when updating the SDK.
8. Select the
   bolts.jar file and press OK
9. Then press Apply and OK

Doing a Gradle Sync (happened automatically for me) should resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check your facebook-sdk/facebook folder to see if there is a libs file (Not directory)

So I think Android studio failed to import the libs as a directory instead included a libs file with "../libs" in it.
Not sure if this was facebook-sdk issue, git cloning issue or android studio issue.

Solution:
1. remove the dummy libs file
2. copy the libs directory manually
3. remove the dependency in project structure
4. add it manually by clicking + sign